# grails plugin limit one session per user at a time

Tags: authentication, grails, plugins

I am using 'plugins.spring-security-core' wondering is there any easy way to limit # of session from a given user to just 1. I tried 'HttpSessionBindingListener' but in the current plugin implementation looks like it just binds the user 'id' and not the full user session as such the appropriate events are not getting called.

I am wondering if any one has come across solution to the above problem.

Thanks in advance

-Amitabh

Comment: But how it's possible to create few user session for one user at one time?

Comment: You can open another browser or log in from other machine, there are various ways you can have multiple session running in parallel for a given user and I am trying to limit that

Comment: hm, what do you mean with session? `request.getSession()`?

Comment: Oh, I got it, do you mean 'one session per one spring security user'?

Comment: @Igor Artamonov yes you got it right

Comment: I'd probably start by implementing my own AuthProdiver (extending AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider) and in the additionalAuthenticationChecks method, check to see if a session for that user already exists.

Comment: @Gregg, can you please elaborate on that a bit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a good example

http://blog.block-consult.com/2012/01/restricting-concurrent-user-sessions-in-grails-2-using-spring-security-core-plugin/

/jörg